# Sorting according to number of characters in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting

I have a table like this:

```
NAME
-----
ABCD
PQRST
QWERTYU
XGGABC
```

I need to show shortest name on the first. I wonder how to sort these like below

```
NAME
-----
ABCD
PQRST
XGGABC
QWERTYU
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
order by len(name), name;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     SELECT * FROM (

     SELECT 'XGGABC' as NAME
     UNION 
     SELECT 'ABCD' AS NAME
     UNION
     SELECT 'PQRST' AS NAME
     UNION
     SELECT 'QWERTYU' AS NAME

     )tmp ORDER BY len(NAME),NAME
```